# How do I install, build and use GDCM with VTK?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake, vtk

I'm having problems getting started with GDCM (Grassroots Dicom). Although I actually could run a VTK example without problem, when I try to use GDCM I'm always getting errors such as:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\\..\\..\\..\bin\Release\vtkgdcm.lib'
```

When I build GDCM it does just fine. I have followed step by step the guides in the GDCM webpage but still I can't run a program successfully. So, anyone can post me a guide or give me some advice?

I'm in Windows7 and working in Visual Studio 2008 and using CMake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late but did you read [Configuring and Building With VS .NET 2003](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Configuring_and_Building_With_VS_.NET_2003)